# Readonly nested object properties

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm having a problem defining these 2 classes:

```
public class Article
{
    public Article(long ID, string Name, ArticleFamily Family)
    {
        //...Initializer...
    }
    public ArticleFamily Family { get; set; }
    //Other props...
}

public class ArticleFamily
{
    public ArticleFamily(int ID, string Description)
    {
        //...Initializer...
    }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of **Article** and each one belongs to a family.
Now, given that I have a certain **ArticleFamily** object I should be able to change its Description and it gets eventually persisted to a DataBase. (I left out that part for simplicity)
But I should not be able to do this:

```
Article art = SomeMethodReturningArticle();
art.Family.Description = "SomeOtherValue";
```

I should be able to change the Family of an **Article** entirely, replacing it with a new **ArticleFamily** object, but I shouldn't be able to change just the description.
Should I create a copy of the **ArticleFamily** class with readonly properties like this:

```
public class ArticleFamilyReadonly
{
    ArticleFamily _family;
    public ArticleFamilyReadonly(ArticleFamily Family)
    {
        _family = Family;
    }
    public int ID { get { return _family.ID; } }
    //etc...
}
```

How can I do this in a clean way?

Comment: Where *should* you be able to change the `Description` from? Consider making the setter `private`.

Comment: Have private setters for Description in ArticleFamile. This will allow just the ArticleFamily alone to modify.

Comment: If I have an ``ArticleFamily`` object I should be able to change the Description, but not through the ``Article`` object itself: ``art.Family.Description = "SomeOtherValue";``

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Do you want `ArticleFamily` to be immutable or not?

Comment: No, I want to be able to change an Article's family to another family. The problem is this design makes it possible to change the nested Family object's properties. If I have a collection of Article objects and do this: ``arts[0].Family.Description = "SomethingElse"`` I will end up with articles which have a Family with same ID but different Family name. This puts the articles in an invalid state...

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I threw together in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var art = new Article(1,"2", new ArticleFamily(1, "Test"));
    art.Family.Description = "What?"; // Won't work

    var fam = art.Family as ArticleFamily;
    fam.Description = "This works"; // This works...

}

public class Article
{
    public Article(long ID, string Name, IArticleFamily Family)
    {
        //...Initializer...
    }
    public IArticleFamily Family { get; set; }
    //Other props...
}

public class ArticleFamily : IArticleFamily
{
    public ArticleFamily(int ID, string Description)
    {
        //...Initializer...
    }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface IArticleFamily
{
    int ID { get; }
    string Description { get;}
}
```

Cannot edit directly from the Article object unless cast to ArticleFamily object.